# Bootstrap Button Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can you use the bootstrap responsive classes on buttons when using `pull-right`?. For example, `<button class="col-xs-6">`. I'm using pull-right to put both my buttons in-line with the header text.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: http://www.bootply.com/bk6be0CBuB

I'd like for these buttons to be wider then they are and break in a responsive manner.

```
 <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Button 2</button>
    </div>
 <h2>Header Text</h2>
```

Comment: Can't you just try it on a big screen and a little screen and see if it works or not? Even better, just open on a big screen and resize the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use those classes on buttons with `pull-right`, and you also can't use percents with `pull-right`. You can make the button sizes be responsive however by setting the width for the buttons at all the different Twitter Bootstrap breakpoints using media queries. Here would be the media query for extra-small devices:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .btn {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Just do that with the desired width of the button at each screen size, and if you are having some issues with sizes in-between breakpoints, make a new media query for that.